# Como converter JSON em XML no ORACLE 11g?

Tags: banco-de-dados, json, xml, oracle, oracle11g

Boa tarde, estou com um problema no meu trabalho.

Preciso criar uma function no oracle que realize a conversão de json para xml e mostrar o resultado como tabela.

Sei que a versão 12 do oracle faz isso facilmente, porém infelizmente nossa base ainda é 11g.

Alguém conhece uma forma de fazer isso no Oracle 11g?

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Erick, você já testou o "[pljson](https://github.com/pljson/pljson)"? Ele faz isso que você precisa, nesse [post](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4478126/how-to-convert-json-into-xml-in-oracle-10g) o recomendaram e sugeriram o seguinte script de teste:

```
declare
    v_json json := json('{
                          "EMPLOYEE":[
                                      {"NAME":"CLARK","JOB":"MANAGER","SALARY":2450},
                                      {"NAME":"KING","JOB":"PRESIDENT","SALARY":5000},
                                      {"NAME":"MILLER","JOB":"CLERK","SALARY":1300}
                                     ]
                         }'
                       );
    v_xml xmltype;
begin
    v_xml := json_xml.json_to_xml(v_json,'EMPLOYEES');
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_xmlgen.convert(v_xml.getclobval(),1));
end;
```